# Creating integer timestamp column from date and time columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataset with the following columns:

```
df=pd.read_csv('file.csv')
df
    time        date
0   21:11:07    2022-08-04
1   21:11:12    2022-08-04
2   21:11:27    2022-08-04
```

How do I get to this:

```
    time        date          timestamp
0   21:11:07    2022-08-04    123238212
1   21:11:12    2022-08-04    123238217
2   21:11:27    2022-08-04    123238227
```

Comment: What is timestamp?  It's not seconds since epoc.

Comment: @AllanWind I meant epoch unix timestamp, the numbers that I put in the column are random

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'] + ' ' + df['time'])
df['unix_timestamp'] = [i.timestamp() for i in df.datetime]
```

Convert date and time to datetime. Then get there timestamp.

Comment: Thanks, I was also looking for a way to turn them into datetime column as well.

Answer (score 1):

I'll leave the pandas code to you, but you want the strptime function from datetime, this should get you there:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> time = '21:11:07'
>>> date = '2022-08-04'
>>> date_time_obj = datetime.strptime(f"{date} {time}", '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
>>> print(date_time_obj.timestamp())
2022-08-04 21:11:07

(That pandas specific answer is probably better, but I'll leave this here.)
```

Answer (score 1):

I have not used pandas before but what about this?

```
from datetime import *
df['timestamp'] = int(datetime.fromisoformat(f"{df['date']} {df['time']}").timestamp())
```

Answer (score 0):

If your column values are dates and times (not strings) then you can do this (I had to subtract 4 hours - 14400 seconds - because of the timezone):

```py
time = [datetime(2022,8,4,21,11,7).time(), datetime(2022,8,4,21,11,7).time()]
date = [datetime(2022,8,4,0,0,0).date(), datetime(2022,8,4,0,0,0).date()]
df = pd.DataFrame({"time":time, "date":date})



df['timestamp']= df.apply(lambda r : int(datetime.combine(r['date'],r['time']).timestamp()-14400),1)
df
```

Output:

```
    time        date        timestamp
0   21:11:07    2022-08-04  1659647467
1   21:11:07    2022-08-04  1659647467
```

Check the timestamp:

```py
pd.to_datetime(1659647467,unit='s')
Timestamp('2022-08-04 21:11:07') ## output
```